# Windows 10 computer can only connect when using an address assigned via DHCP

Tags: windows-10, networking, dhcp, static-ip

#### The Problem

My computer will only connect to the internet if it has an address assigned via DHCP.  Otherwise if I statically set an address, it will be ignored and use the Windows default address of 169.254.X.X.

#### What I have tried

Switching from Static to DHCP and back again.

Unplugging my computer's ethernet cable.

Turning my router back off and on.

Rebooting my computer.

Disabling my anti-virus (Clam Sentinel).

#### Possible causes?

A malformed update from Windows?

My router is starting to fail?

My networking card is starting to fail?

My switch is starting to fail?

#### Why I need it solved

Several applications require a static IP address to function properly.  For example, OBS requires a static IP to stream, and I host Garry's Mod from time to time, and would prefer to not update the port forwarding frequently.

#### Other Info

SSH'd into my Linux Mint server (has a static IP), and pinged out.  No issue.

Gave my Android 8, Blu Vivo XL 4 phone a static IP on the network.  Unable to connect.

The computer is connected via Ethernet, not WiFi.

Running Windows 10 Professional, activated.

Using a basic networking switch.  Not smart, not PoE.


Should I have further updates, I will edit them into this post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Is the static address one still in the DHCP pool? 1) Why not set the static on your DHCP server, thereby removing it from the pool?

Comment: Please include in your post the static IP address and the DHCP segment configured for the router (address range & netmask).

Answer (score 0):

So the router's DHCP was the culprit. Some how the DHCP address pool on the router had expanded beyond what I had configured it for, and another device had some how got the same address.

Thanks anyway for all your help.